# MSSQL JDBC Driver library path is not recognized when using ~/ when running Logstash manually

Tags: linux, logstash, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

Currently trying to populate the employee index with the below settings:

**CONF**

```
input {
  jdbc {
    jdbc_driver_library => "~/sqljdbc_6.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar"
    jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://SERVER;user=USER;password=PASSWORD"
    jdbc_user => "DB_USER"
    jdbc_password => "DB_PASSWORD"
    jdbc_validate_connection => true
    jdbc_validation_timeout => -1
    statement => "SELECT * FROM [dbo].Employee ORDER BY ID"
    type => "employee"
  }
}
filter {
}
output {
}
```

NOTE: *filter* and *output* sections of the conf file is purposely blank

**LINUX COMMAND**

```
sudo /usr/share/logstash/bin/logstash -f /home/ubuntu/Employee-pipeline.conf --path.settings /etc/logstash/ --path.data /var/lib/logstash_new
```

**RESULT**
[image]
Looks like logstash does not know or don't have access to ~/sqljdbc...*.jar

I also confirmed that the *mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar* exists
[image]

However, when I changed the path to **/home/ubuntu/sqljdbc_6.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar**, it runs successfully.

So **~/** is the same as **/home/ubuntu**

This started to occur after upgrading our Elastic Stack from v5.5 to v5.6. Also, note that this does not occur if we run the same conf file with the logstash service.

Comment: remove the quotes around the tilde: ~"/sqljdbc_6.2/enu/mssql-jdbc-6.2.1.jre8.jar". See the difference between `sudo echo ~` and `sudo echo "~"`

Comment: @Roadowl `sudo echo ~/sqljdbc...` results to `/home/ubuntu/sqljdbc...` while `sudo echo "~/sqljdbc..."` results to `~/sqljdbc...`. The .conf file contains JSON format so I think having quotes there is fine.